# Toggle the text based on the 'Y' or 'N' values

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angular JS.  In my html page i have a 'td' for showing the status as 'Approved' OR 'Not Approved' based on the 'Y' and 'N' values.  This Y and N values am getting from service.And it is stored in an array called ApprovedList.

```html
 <tr class="row txt-gray-666 text-semibold font13 text-tranUp" ng-repeat="items in ApprovedList">
  <td class="n-wrap txt-green">{{items.IsApproved}}</td>.
```

This will display the status field as Y or N

How can I write a scope/function to change the text based on Y or N
If it is IsApproved='Y' it should display as 'Approved' .  If IsApproved='N' it should display as 'Not approved'.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple, you modify your expression in `<td>` as below:

```
<tr class="row txt-gray-666 text-semibold font13 text-tranUp" ng-repeat="items in ApprovedList">
  <td class="n-wrap txt-green">{{(items.IsApproved == 'Y')? 'Approved' : 'Not Approved'}}</td>.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to create a method in the controller. This is preferable because you can test it. Also, if your logic grows big, it is not a problem.

```js
$scope.isApproved = function(value) {
  if(value ==='Y') {
    return 'Approved';
  }
  return 'Not Approved';
};
```

```html
<tr class="row txt-gray-666 text-semibold font13 text-tranUp" ng-repeat="items in ApprovedList">
  <td class="n-wrap txt-green">{{isApproved(items.IsApproved)}}</td>.
```